# primefaces 5.1 file upload not responding

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces

I am trying to open browsing window with this file upload code but it is not responding means the pop up window not opening

```
<p:fileUpload id="fileupload" value="#{data.value}" fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadController.handleFileUpload}"
 required="true" allowTypes="#{data.allowedExtensions}" mode="advanced" multiple="true"
           update="fileDataTable _mainForm_fileMessages" widgetVar="fileUploadWidget" />
```

Comment: Press F12 in browser and check the console. Any clues there?

Comment: You realy have to improve your your basic debugging skills

Comment: @meta I wonder how people get upvotes on questions like this. I rarely get one for a researched answer?

Comment: Some JavaScript errors are very likely. Do as directed in previous comments.